# How to debug office add-in for mac?

Tags: office-js

I am developing a MS office add-in for Word. The test version is working fine on Word for Windows, but fails on Office for Mac.

On Office for Mac, the add-in loads as it is supposed to, but whenever I try to click a button that executes a JS script that calls on a php web service that communicates with a MySQL database, nothing happens.

I don't get any error messages, so I am looking for advice on how to debug the add-in on a mac. What tools can I use?

For background, I have tried

1. The Vorlon.js guidance here:
   https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mim/2016/02/18/vorlonjs-plugin-for-debugging-office-addin/

But it does not seem to work. The problem might be that I am not very familiar with Git, and following the instructions literally might not work.

2. I have also tried loading the add-in directly in Chrome, and using the Dev tools. This does not work because the add-in depends on an API that it can only access when it is launched via Word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is most likely with HTTPS. Add-ins require HTTPS, and by extension any scripts that they use must be HTTPS as well, including the Vorlon script. Therefore, you have to configure Vorlon to use SSL in order to use Vorlon with add-ins.

If you installed Vorlon using git, you should know where the Vorlon folder is. If you installed it with npm, I found it in **/usr/local/lib/node_modules**. Under the vorlon/ folder, go to the Server folder and edit the **config.json** file. If you installed with npm, you'll need to ctrl-click > Get Info > unlock and change the permissions to Read & Write because they are Read Only by default. In the config.json file, change the **useSSL** property to **true**. While you're there, you can also enable the Office plugin if you want.

Now you can start the vorlon server with the command `sudo vorlon`, and it should run with SSL. You will need to trust the certificate, which you should be prompted to do when you navigate to https://localhost:1337, or otherwise you can find the certificate file in the vorlon folder under /Server/cert.

Make sure that the  element in your add-in's default html file (such as home.html) now uses the https URL, i.e. **https://localhost:1337/vorlon.js**.

Now you should be able to see connected clients in the Vorlon interface and debug your add-in.

We need to update our debugging topic to better reflect these setup requirements. Thank you for identifying this gap!

Comment: This was it, thank you! The problem was that I had actually installed it both via npm and git, and then edited the wrong config.json to enable ssl. Well, great learning for a beginner like myself.

Comment: @harrison-shapley (repeating another comment) We've used Vorlon.js in the past but, we've never been able to use it for debugging the JS code. We've had to litter the code with console.logs and look at the console to figure out what's happening. Is there a way to set breakpoints and have the same debugging experience as you'd have with F12 Dev Tools or VS?

Comment: @Sameera vorlon.js does not support breakpoints. Currently there are not any methods we recommend to debug add-ins with breakpoints on Office for Mac, however you could do so in the browser and then simply check that the add-in runs as you expect on Office for Mac.

Comment: Thanks @harrison-shapley. That's what we do now. But, we've run in to several issues that are Office for Mac specific (discussed elsewhere) that don't even repro on Safari on Mac. Figuring them out had been painful due to the lack of a debugger.

Comment: UPDATE ON THIS ISSUE: Microsoft has improved the article that the original poster linked to. The instructions for working with HTTPs are now more detailed and explicit.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-office-add-ins-on-ipad-and-mac is now updated with the following guide you can use to use Safari Web Inspector for the Mac:

To be able to debug Office Add-ins on Mac, you must have Mac OS High Sierra AND Mac Office Version: 16.9.1 (Build 18012504) or later. If you don't have an Office Mac build, you can get one by joining the Office 365 Developer program.

To start, open a terminal and set the OfficeWebAddinDeveloperExtras property for the relevant Office application as follows:

defaults write com.microsoft.Word OfficeWebAddinDeveloperExtras -bool true

defaults write com.microsoft.Excel OfficeWebAddinDeveloperExtras -bool true

defaults write com.microsoft.Powerpoint OfficeWebAddinDeveloperExtras -bool true

defaults write com.microsoft.Outlook OfficeWebAddinDeveloperExtras -bool true

Then, open the Office application and insert your add-in. Right-click the add-in and you should see an Inspect Element option in the context menu. Select that option and it will pop the Inspector, where you can set breakpoints and debug your add-in.

> Note

Please note that this is an experimental feature and there are no guarantees that we will preserve this functionality in future versions of Office applications.

Comment: Is there a way to do this when downloaded Office from App Store?

Comment: "If you don't have an Office Mac build, you can get one by joining the Office 365 Developer program."

Can't seem to find the link.  :shrug

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried taking a look at these two topics?

http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/sideload-an-office-add-in-on-ipad-and-mac

http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/debug-office-add-ins-on-ipad-and-mac

Comment: Yes. I'm following the sideloading instructions for testing and the debugging article refers to the blog post I linked to in my original post. The problem is, at least for me, that I can't get Vorlon.js to work by following the instructions.  Either they are outdated, incomplete or I am doing something wrong.  I was thus hoping someone would have better instructions.

Comment: Ok, that's what I needed to know.  Let me follow up on that with my team...

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky We've used Vorlon.js in the past but, we've never been able to use it for debugging the JS code. We've had to litter the code with console.logs and look at the console to figure out what's happening. Is there a way to set breakpoints and have the same debugging experience as you'd have with F12 Dev Tools or VS?

Comment: @Sameera, I would recommend asking Harrison, author of the other answer.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelZlatkovsky. Just wondering if Office dev team can also help regarding this; perhaps supporting the Chrome Debugging Protocol on the embedded Webkit instance that runs in Office for Mac so that something like https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug will be a viable debugger

Comment: Yep, good suggestion as well.  And again, Harrison is probably the best one here to take the comment to the dev team.  You could also add your idea to https://officespdev.uservoice.com/, and cross-link to it from here.

Comment: @Sameera I will pass your suggestion along to the dev team.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelZlatkovsky and harrison-shapley
I've added https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/suggestions/15952222-support-a-debugger-for-mac-desktop-clients as well

Comment: @Sameera Found any debugging possibility for JS code?

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky-Microsoft We have different behavoir on Powerpoint Online on a Mac and inside the Mac Desktop app (both Safari!?) 
Any chance to view the console log inside a desktop app. 
JS debugging seems too far away :(

Comment: @ndee, let me direct your comment to someone on my team, who works on Mac add-in integration.

Comment: @ndee Unfortunately no. Nothing beyond Vorlon.

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky-Microsoft VorlonJs is NOT working at the moment on Mac due to a dependency error with phantomjs. 
see this for details https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/Vorlonjs/issues/433
I worked around with not installing vorlon globally. But hey - this is real hard to fix the debugger prior to debugging...

Comment: @Sameera Vorlog is not working on a Mac as described on MS Office.js documentation.  see previous comment