# debug office 365 taskpane app on Mac?

Tags: macos, office-js, vorlon

I am trying to debug task pane app on a Mac. Already tried https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/debug-office-add-ins-on-ipad-and-mac. I can see it detects browser instances but it CANNOT detect task pane app.

I followed all steps properly. Except, that I don't have "Staff" user group on my mac. Should that make difference?

How do I detect/debug office task pane app on a mac?

Comment: INFO: I have already gone through this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39146285/how-to-debug-office-add-in-for-mac

Comment: You have to be logged into the machine as an administrator when you install/setup/use vorlon. The fact that you can't see a Staff group makes me suspect that you are not logged into the machine as an administrator.

Comment: Thank you for the direction. @RickKirkham .. This time I did all steps again as admin. Installed vorlon with admin account also did saw the "Staff" user group as well. And still result was the same. :( vorlon can't detect office add-in (task pane app) !

Comment: A couple things to try next. (1) Run the task pane add-in. Then open a browser and navigate to the add-in's home page in a browser window, does vorlon see the browser client? If not, that might mean that the page is not configured to use vorlon. Redo the section "Configure the add-in for Vorlon.JS debugging". Be sure you've got the <script> tag correct.

Comment: (2) Search the entire machine for "vorlon" to find all the folders/files with that name. It may take a long time to run if you have a big drive and a lot of files. When it finishes, look to see if you have multiple instances of vorlon installed. This is known to cause puzzling symptoms in vorlon. If there's more than one, I recommend uninstalling all instances and then reinstalling using the instructions in the article that you linked to. The you'll need to redo the rest of the setup.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers @RickKirkham. I already did these steps. I am sure and verified that Vorlon detects browser instances of my app but if same app is used as a Word task-pane add-in, then its NOT detected.

I also verified that Vorlon is installed just Once using npm at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/vorlon. This is the only installation of vorlon on my mac.

Comment: When Vorlon detects the browser instances of the app, are you opening the app with https or http?

Comment: Its always https

Comment: I've asked for help around the office and I will report back to you anything that I discover. In the meantime, what is OS version on the Mac and what is the version of Office?

Comment: Mac OS Version - 10.12.4 and
Word for Mac - 15.3 (170409)

Comment: @RickKirkham Any updates?

Comment: I asked again for help today and I'll report anything I learn. Near the end of the topic you linked to, there is a mention of an Office plug-in for Vorlon. Does enabling or disabling that plug-in make any difference?

Comment: I'm afraid we don't have any real Vorlon experts on staff and I am not able to reproduce your symptoms. The best we can suggest is that you check out Vorlon's documentation (http://vorlonjs.com/#getting-started). Perhaps they have information about how Vorlon discovers clients.

Comment: I was successful this time, I used chrome before that allowed me to access vorlon, So i never got to go on step 13 in the [documentation](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/debug-office-add-ins-on-ipad-and-mac). This time I used safari and then trusted certificate and then it worked like charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used chrome before that allowed me to access vorlon by choosing option to navigate to untrusted https website. So I never got to go on step 13 in the [documentation](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/debug-office-add-ins-on-ipad-and-mac). This time I used safari and then I had to trusted certificate and then after it worked like charm.