# How to inpsect console logs of outlook add-in on mac?

Tags: macos, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

### Problem

I can't debug or inspect console logs on my outlook add-in while developing on my mac.

### What I've tried

According to other questions ([How to debug office add-in for mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39146285/how-to-debug-office-add-in-for-mac), [debug office 365 taskpane app on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43885976/debug-office-365-taskpane-app-on-mac)), one of the following should work:

- the Safari Web Inspector (this unfortunately doesn't work for me, I've asked about this on MS'Q&A Forum [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/968905/how-can-i-use-the-safari-web-inspector-on-outlook.html))
- the VSCode Debugger extension (this doesn't work for me either, I've filed a [GH issue](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Addin-Scripts/issues/667) about this with a reproduction repository attached)
- downloading a non-app store build as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65100273/how-to-debug-microsoft-outlook-for-mac-or-windows-web-add-in)

I haven't tried [VorlonJS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/mim/vorlonjs-plugin-for-debugging-office-addin) because it seems overly complicated and I'd ideally not resort to a third-party plugin.

Comment: Please run this command in console- 
defaults write com.microsoft.Outlook OfficeWebAddinDeveloperExtras -bool true
This will enable inspect elements options in Add-in

Answer (score 2):

Please run this command in console- defaults write com.microsoft.Outlook OfficeWebAddinDeveloperExtras -bool true
This will enable inspect elements options in Add-in